# MySQL - specify a column value during insert with result of select

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql 5.7 and have a user table that looks something like this:

```
create table user (
   id          int unsigned   not null auto_increment primary key ,
   first_name  varchar(30)    not null                            ,
   last_name   varchar(30)    not null                            ,
   user_name   varchar(15)    not null unique                     ,
   email       varchar(100)   not null                            ,
   phone       varchar(255)       null                            ,
   address     varchar(100)       null                            ,
   created_by  int unsigned   not null                            ,
   created_on  timestamp      not null                            ,
   modified_on timestamp          null                           );
```

I insert one row into the table like this in order to create a kind of "admin" user for my application.

```
insert into user value (0, "plm", "admin", "plm_admin",  "do_not_replay@my_company.com", "111-222-3333", null, 1, now(), null);
```

I then want to insert more users into the user table.  But when doing so, I want to specify that the "created_by" field is set to the id of the "system" user I just created, "plm_admin".

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
insert into user value (0, "steve", "smith", "ssmith" , "steve.smith@my_company.com", "111-222-4444", null, select id from user where user_name = "plm_admin", now(), null);
```

This sql doesn't work, but hopefully you get the idea that when inserting the values for user steve smith, I want to specify the id for user "plm_admin" as the value for the "created_by" column.

Comment: Not sure with MySQL, but you need the MSSql equivalent of SCOPE_IDENTITY to get the primary key of the last insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

Also, your insert had one column too many - value of "Active" didn't appear to have a column to go with it

```
insert into user value (0, "plm", "admin", "plm_admin", "do_not_replay@my_company.com", "111-222-3333", null, 1, now(), null);
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into user value (1, "steve", "smith", "ssmith" , "steve.smith@my_company.com", "111-222-4444", null, @id, now(), null);
insert into user value (2, "john", "smith", "jsmith" , "john.smith@my_company.com", "111-222-4444", null, @id, now(), null);
```

Comment: That sql code works, but is not the behavior I want.

Comment: I want all subsequent users who are inserted into the user table to have the "created_by" field set to the id for user "plm_admin".

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I need!   Thank you so much!